# ¿Como seleccionar todos los ultimos registros que tengan una columna con el mismo valor?

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla donde inserto  una id de otra tabla ('Idstock') y queria seleccionar 
todos los ultimos registros que tengan una id igual en esa columna

Por ejemplo  si tengo 6 registros  las columnas serian :

```
'idMov' / 'Idstock',/'Descripcion'/

  1     /       1   /     producto1

  2     /      1     /   producto1

  3     /      1     /   producto1

  4    /       2    /    producto2

  5    /       2    /    producto2

  6    /       3    /    producto3
```

quiero seleccionar todos los ultimos registros que tengan el mismo valor en 'Idstock' 
para que salga asi :

```
'idMov' / 'Idstock', 'Descripcion'

3 / 1 / Producto1

5 / 2 / Producto2

6 / 3 / Producto3
```

hice este select pero solo me trae el ultimo registro siempre y cuando tenga  el valor igual en Idstock :

```
SELECT m.idMov,st.Idstock,st.Descripcion FROM movimientos m  inner join stock_inicial st on m.idStockI=st.idStockI WHERE m.idMov = (SELECT MAX(m.idMov) from movimientos m WHERE m.Idstock=2)
```

me traeria solo esto

```
'IdMov' / 'Idstock' / 'Descripcion' 

5 / 2 / Producto2
```

Alguien podria ayudarme ?

Comment: entonces....es MySQL o SQL Server?

Comment: Es MySQL pero como es un select creo que no es diferente

Comment: si luis, es muy diferente porque no tienen exactamente las mismas funciones.. en este caso es trivial, pero en otros no...

Comment: Si ya se que es diferente pero como este select es 'simple' etiquete a todo sql

Comment: Si bueno, pero no debes etiquetar todo porque si. Trata de tener mas cuidado y solo poner las etiquetas relevantes a la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que muestras en tu datos, las columnas Idstock y Descripcion son siempre iguales.

Guiandome por los datos que estas mostrando, la consulta se resuelve simplemente agrupando por ellas dos, y mostrando el max de la columna idMov. Es importante que se entienda que el concepto de "ultimo" no existe en una base de datos, a menos que vos lo marques de alguna forma (un timestamp?).

```
SELECT MAX(m.idMov),st.Idstock,st.Descripcion 
FROM movimientos m inner join stock_inicial st on m.idStockI=st.idStockI
group by st.idstock, st.descripcion
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, y como seria si tengo otro valor que si cambia ? 'cantidad'

Comment: E agregado la columa pero me trae la cantidad del 'primer registro' que tiene  el mismo valor en 'Idstock'

Comment: habria que analizar ese modelo. Tendria que saber cual valor de esa columna queres traer @Luis

Comment: Son dos tipos de datos uno numerico y otro texto  las columnas serian 'cantidad'  y la otra  'TipoDocumento'

Comment: Debo abrir otra pregunta ? o edito esta ?

Comment: y que datos de esas columnas? no se soluciona joineandolas despues? (que es lo que probablemente haya que hacer)... @Luis